# Are the Great Lakes Getting Cleaner, or worse?

Tags: water, pollution, water-table

I live in Hamilton Ontario which a major city right on the shore of Lake Ontario, and I was just doing some personal research on the pollution levels in lake Ontario. Generally the water here has a negative stigma of being dirty, and I was just wondering, are the lakes getting cleaner, or like greenhouse gases; It depends where you are talking about.

I was always under the impression that the factories here in Hamilton Harbor were a large source of pollution, and apparently they were at one point, but now days its non point source pollution that is apparently creating the most pollution in Lake Ontario.